# Ajax PHP/Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, prototype

I return an array of a customer's addresses with PHP via Ajax (return as addresses). 
I document.write the addresses.responseText which displays the array perfectly

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [addressID] => 15804 [customerID] => 10 [loanID] => [address1] => 6 Road [address2] => [address3] => [town] => Their Town [county] => Their County [postCode] => Their postCode [reason] => [current] => 1 [timestamp] => 2013-03-13 14:41:39 ) [1] => Array ( [addressID] => 10 [customerID] => 10 [loanID] => [address1] => 21A Road [address2] => [address3] => [town] => Their 2nd Town [county] => Their 2nd County [postCode] => Their 2nd postCode [reason] => [current] => 0 [timestamp] => 2013-03-13 14:41:39 ) )
```

I'm having problem though with looping through and using the array information.

```
new Ajax.Request('includes/ajax.php',
        {
            method:'post',
            parameters: {addCustID: customerID},
            onSuccess: function(addresses){

            document.write(addresses.responseText);

                for (var i in addresses)
                {

                    if(i == "responseText") 
                    {                           
                        addressExpander.addEntry(addresses[i]);
                    }
                }
            },
            onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
        });
```

I want to run `addressExpander.addEntry(addresses[i]);` for each address, but it only displays once, not for each address.

I've tried looping through `addresses.responseText` in the `if(i == "responseText")` loop but it doesn't do anything.

I'm using Prototype by the way, it is already being used in the page.

Comment: change `if(i == "responseText")` for `if(addresses[i] == "responseText")` otherwise you're comparing the index instead of the actual value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks, though I did that and now addressExpander.addEntry(addresses[i]); doesn't run at all

Comment: That means none of the values contained in `addresses` hold the value `"responseText"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem you're having is that there are pretty significant differences between [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [Javascript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

To help compensate for these difference, our overlords created the almighty JSON format which helps enable the sharing of inter-language data structures. Before echoing your PHP response, use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like so:

```
echo json_encode($your_php_arr);
```

Your JS code should be able to work without any modifications. If it doesn't, try adding a `JSON.parse` within your onSuccess callback:

```
var your_js_arr = JSON.parse(addresses.responseText);

for (var i in your_js_arr)
{               
    addressExpander.addEntry(your_js_arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get 2 address blocks as wanted which is good, but there are also 37 blank ones produced after that.

Comment: It loops 39 times instead of 2

Comment: Wierd as my php array produces 2 addresses as in my original example

Comment: Solved it, I added 'if (your_js_arr[i]['address1']) addressExpander.addEntry(your_js_arr[i]);'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this line:

```
document.write(addresses.responseText);
```

is the one that's producing the output you posted, you're printing out addresses.responseText and it's the array of addresses.

As you said in your answer, by the looks of it, you need to loop through addresses.responseText instead:

```
for (var i=0;i<addresses.responseText.length;i++)
{     
     addressExpander.addEntry(addresses.responseText[i]);
}
```

Comment: I did try that, it loop about 50 times!